# Pushing a Pick List to a checkout Terminal from a mobile Device

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

I have a mobile App for picking goods, Developed in Xamarin Forms/Android to pick items via Barcode in Store. I would like to send that basket for finalising to a terminal PC running a UWP app for final processing. I would like to do this like in supermarket SCAN the Terminals QR code and the Pick List appears on it. How is this done and what API in .Net can achieve this?

Any pointers to get me started greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is far too broad and vague to be answered on SO.  But I would generally suggest that any system like this uses a centralized database shared by both the mobile app and the checkout terminal

Comment: Just to extend I am looking at the UWP waiting for a notification to load a Basket up from the server initiated by a mobile device scanning it's QR code. I have used windows messaging services (a while ago) but not to sure how this space has matured since then.